# Is it even useful to report cheating anymore?

Tags: ethics, united-states, undergraduate, cheating

I'm taking my 8th course since the Covid-19 shutdown of universities has forced everyone to come home. When looking up stuff, I have inevitably come across almost all the questions from psets, quizzes, tests, etc posted to Chegg, where I presume other students are cheating. I am 100% sure these are from the current term's class questions, as the questions are usually rewritten every term by the profs in my department and are posted as a picture, so sometimes one can even see the header for the current term (not to mention the picture is directly of the question paper). I think at this point it is a fair assumption to make that there is cheating going on.

In my first 7 courses, I reported this, to varying degrees of success. All the professors tried to address this, but some basically told me even they couldn't do much about it. Even after the "mass cleansing" that happened after each of these reports, almost every question I searched about could be found on Chegg.

My 8th course just started and I'm already seeing questions on Chegg. I understand the professor's predicament of them not being able to do anything and don't want to become the student constantly pointing out flaws in their enforcement of academic misconduct (as doing this would probably cause the prof to grow to resent me through misattribution of arousal). However, it's extremely frustrating to slog out a class and be working 16 hour days when others are cheating their way through a course (not to mention destroying the curve, making it even harder for me).

At this point, does it even make sense to report this to the prof?

*I phrased the question title as such because I suspect many others are going through the same problem during Covid-19*

Comment: You aren't reporting cheating.  You are reporting the opportunity to cheat.  This is very different.

Comment: You were right to report it, but after a few reports they probably got the point. Stop comparing to others and keep studying instead of cheating, it will pay off in the long run because you learn something and cheaters don't

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I mean someone has to post it and I think it's fair to say that that given the post (and the post's intention) and given the opportunity to cheat, the person in question is probably cheating.

Comment: @Louic I don't report any more than once per class, but it is still somewhat frustrating

Comment: I don't know that the person who intends to cheat is at your university.  You might know that.  In any case, if you can't identify them it's not particularly helpful to report it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist To answer your question, the question is directly off the question paper usually (sometimes even with the current semester and teacher name there) and most of my profs write their own questions. But thank you for the advice.

Comment: Please edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist You might be surprised how many naïve professors there are. I think he should definitely report it to raise awareness about how cheating works in 2020

Comment: @Louic and you might be surprised at how many of us also sat the student side of the desk. I had a student complain that she had a different mark to her friend who she copied off - her friend had all correct and she was most upset that I had changed the order of the answers on her version. I did not have to say anything - the rest of the class were laughing **so** hard....

Comment: Why are you looking up stuff on Chegg? Isn't that cheating?

Comment: @shoover if I look something up that has wording similar to the question, the chegg link will come up (usually high in the Google results). If I click it out of curiosity, I can see the question (as described above)

Comment: Presumably you're looking up "questions from psets, quizzes, tests, etc" after the "psets, quizzes, tests, etc" are over.

Comment: @shoover of course, unless allowed otherwise. For example, I am allowed to look up help on psets, but I am not allowed to have someone else do my work or copy the work directly off someone. Thus, I may look up a concept that I am having trouble with, but if my phrasing is specific to the class (ex. the class has a slightly different name for a common term), the chegg results come up first.

Comment: Neil deGrasse Tyson: When students cheat on exams, it's because our school system values grades more than students value learning.

Comment: Some relevant Math Educators posts about Chegg and cheating: [1](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/18479/), [2](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/what-websites-allow-students-to-purchase-solutions-to-problems), [3](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18449/how-now-shall-we-teach-math-online)

Answer (score 4):

In general it is useful to report cheating.  Some institutions require students to report it.

In this case, however, you do not know who cheated and faculty have already made reasonable efforts to make cheating harder.  The information you are providing is not doing anything to reduce cheating, so you can stop reporting it.

Comment: Someone who has used Chegg might have more information.